# How can I make this type of substitution in maple?

Tags: maple

I have tried using subs but it is not working for what I am trying to do.

I have

```
r2 := (n_x^2+n_y^2-1);
```

and I want this expression:

```
E:=hbar*Pi/(2*M*A)*(n_x^2/L+n_y^2/L);
```

to put r2 in so I can solve for r2 (using maple). Does anyone know what the command is to do this? I cannot seem to articulate what I want well enough to bring it up in the help search!

Comment: Why don't you do it by hand? Clearly, `(n_x^2/L+n_y^2/L)` is equal to `(r2+1)/L`. Hence, you can set `E:=hbar*Pi/(2*M*A)*(r2+1)/L;` and solve whatever you want with that.

Comment: because I know how to do it by hand already @5pm

Comment: Then it's not really a mathematical question, is it? It should not be asked at Math.SE. // Anyway, you can include the information about r2 as additional equation in the system you are solving: `solve([hbar*Pi/(2*M*A)*(n_x^2/L+n_y^2/L)=42, r2=(n_x^2+n_y^2-1)], [r2, A, M]);`

Comment: While there is no SE for mathematical computing it is fine for math SE, don't you think?

Comment: I don't. The fact that you can't find a better place to ask a question does not mean it's fine to ask it here.

Comment: It's not a question about how to best keep my laundry colours from dying my lights, it's directly related to mathematics.

Comment: @5pm The last time I asked on meta about questions concerning mathematical software [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4974/the-limit-of-questions-concerning-mathematical-software) there wasn't a lot of attention. But *the* answer stated that such questions were welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assigning a value to r2 you made it (nearly) impossible to evaluate any expression and see an r2 in it.  Get rid of that assignment:

```
> r2:= 'r2':
```

Now subs won't work because the expression you want to be r2 doesn't appear as an operand in E.  However, you can use

```
> simplify(E, {n_x^2+n_y^2-1 = r2});
```

$${\frac {{\it hbar}\,\pi \,{\it r2}}{2\,MAL}}+{\frac {{\it hbar}
\,\pi }{2\,MAL}}
$$

or

```
> algsubs(n_x^2+n_y^2-1 = r2, E);
```

$$ \frac{{\it hbar}\, \pi ({\it r2}+1)}{2\, MAL}$$

Comment: The only problem with that is I can't then solve for r2 and this is my motivation for subbing it in.

Comment: Solving for `r2` doesn't mean a whole lot when it itself is a relation of two other independent variables, `n_x` and `n_y`. The best you will get is a solution manifold, some curve, plane, or other subset of the Cartesian product of `n_x` and `n_y`'s domains.

Comment: Why not just put in `r2` explicitly, solve for it, and then reconcile the issue with `n_x` and `n_y`?